# ¿Cómo cambiar dinámicamente el contenido de un listbox en base a la opción elegida en un select usando tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

Tengo un diccionario que tiene, para cada nombre de provincias de un país, ciudades pertenecientes a dichas provincias. Debido a que las ciudades son muchas, no puedo usar dos selects (uno para provincias y otro para ciudades). El código que tengo es el siguiente:

```
import tkinter as tk

dictionary = {"Provincia 1":["Ciudad 1", "Ciudad 2", "Ciudad 3"], "Provincia 2":["Ciudad 1", "Ciudad 2", "Ciudad 3"],"Provincia 3":["Ciudad 1", "Ciudad 2", "Ciudad 3"],}

class App(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
       tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
       self.dict = dictionary
       self.variable_provincia = tk.StringVar(self)
       self.variable_ciudad = tk.StringVar(self)
       self.variable_provincia.trace('w', self.updateoptions)
       self.optionmenu_provincia = tk.OptionMenu(self, self.variable_provincia, *self.dict.keys())
       self.optionmenu_ciudad = tk.OptionMenu(self, self.variable_ciudad, '')
       self.optionmenu_provincia.pack()
       self.optionmenu_ciudad.pack()
       self.pack()
    def updateoptions(self, *args):
       provincias = self.dict[self.variable_provincia.get()]
       self.variable_ciudad.set(provincias[0])
       menu = self.optionmenu_ciudad['menu']
       menu.delete(0, 'end')
       for provincia in provincias:
           menu.add_command(label=provincia, command=lambda provincia=provincia: self.variable_ciudad.set(provincia))

root = tk.Tk()
app = App(root)
app.mainloop()
```

Desearía que en base a la opción del select de provincias, me cambie el contenido en un listbox (que contendría a las ciudades), pero no sabría como implementarlo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En realidad no es muy diferente a lo que ya haces con el `OptionMenu`:

- Se eliminan todos los items que existan con `tkinter.Listbox.delete(0, tk.END)`
- Se insertan los nuevos usando un `for` y `tkinter.Listbox.insert(tk.END, item)`

Es decir, algo así:

```
import tkinter as tk

dictionary = {"Provincia 1":["Ciudad 1", "Ciudad 2", "Ciudad 3"],
              "Provincia 2":["Ciudad 4", "Ciudad 5", "Ciudad 6"],
              "Provincia 3":["Ciudad 7", "Ciudad 8", "Ciudad 9"],}

class App(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
       tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
       self.dict = dictionary
       self.variable_provincia = tk.StringVar(self)
       self.variable_ciudad = tk.StringVar(self)
       self.variable_provincia.trace('w', self.updateoptions)
       self.optionmenu_provincia = tk.OptionMenu(self, self.variable_provincia, *self.dict.keys())
       self.listbox_ciudad = tk.Listbox(self)
       self.listbox_ciudad.bind('<<ListboxSelect>>', self.ciudad_seleccionada)
       self.optionmenu_provincia.pack()
       self.listbox_ciudad.pack()
       self.pack()

    def updateoptions(self, *args):
       provincias = self.dict[self.variable_provincia.get()]
       self.variable_ciudad.set(provincias[0])
       self.listbox_ciudad.delete(0, tk.END)
       for provincia in provincias:
           self.listbox_ciudad.insert(tk.END, provincia)

    def ciudad_seleccionada(self, event):
        w = event.widget
        ind = w.curselection()[0]
        ciudad = w.get(ind)
        print(ciudad)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = App(root)
    app.mainloop()
```